# Can you await an async member function in another async member function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've got a class that does something like the following:

```
class Loader
{
    async load()
    {
        let pending = [...];
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => 
        {
            while(pending.length > 0)
            {
                await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
            }
            resolve();
        });
    }

    async _loadAsset(asset)
    {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>
        {
            // Loading logic goes here, eventually calling...
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

(`pending` is an array of objects that I'm too lazy to list out here.)

The problem I'm having is that Chrome is giving me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` error when I try to load my script. As far as I can tell, Loader's `load` and `_loadAsset` methods have both been declared async. What am I missing? Is the while loop complicating things?

Comment: theres no need to return new promise from these. thats what the `async` modifier does for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function is not declared `async`, so you could try adding async like:

```
return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => 
  {
    while(pending.length > 0) {
      await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
  }
  resolve();
});
```

But an even better option for resolving a lot of pending promised is the [Promise.all() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Hey, that's done it! I knew I'd forgotten an async somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alex using the promise constructor in an async labeled function is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your `load` function to:

```
async load()
{
    let pending = [...];
    while(pending.length > 0)
    {
        await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
    }
}
```

Theres no need for the inner promise construction.

You could also do this:

```
load()
{
    let pending = [...];
    return Promise.all(pending.map(i => this._loadAsset(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the anonymous function you're passing to the `Promise` constructor uses `await` but is not declared `async`:

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>  // this function uses await but is not async
    {
        while(pending.length > 0)
        {
            await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
        }
        resolve();
    });
```

Generally you won't need to use the `Promise` constructor if you're not wrapping something that takes a callback. In this case, you don't need it at all, you can just have the while loop be part of `load`'s body:

```
async load()
{
    let pending = [/*...*/];
    while(pending.length > 0)
    {
        await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a promise from an `async` function. That's because under the hood, any value returned from `async` functions will be wrapped into a promise:

```
// The following function
async function foo() {
    await someAsyncFunction();
    return "done";
}

// Is the same as
function bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        someAsyncFunction().then(() => resolve("done"));
    });
}
```

So your code should be rewritten to:

```
class Loader
{
    async load()
    {
        let pending = [...];

        while(pending.length > 0)
        {
            await this._loadAsset(pending.pop());
        }
    }

    async _loadAsset(asset)
    {
        // Loading logic happens here, but instead of calling resolve(), just return. Remember to add await to any async operation.
    }
}
```